# Date Formatting In Solr Search

Tags: apache, search, solr

I am inserting date in this format into Solr - (2015-11-10T10:24:53+00:00), but when I fire a search query, it returns the results in this format - (2015-11-0T10:24:53Z).

How can I get the date in exactly the format I inserted in?

Comment: did you mention any date format in the schema.xml ?

Comment: check if this helps you https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates

Comment: yeah i mentioned with "tdates" in managed-schema.xml and i have already checked with the link u r suggesting! but couldn't get what i want exaclty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr does not have any concept of time zones, and UTC (2015-11-10T10:24:53Z) is the only format supported.

You'll have to convert on the way out in your display layer and when indexing (if they're both identical and you don't have to consider time zones, you can just pretend they're UTC to Solr).

Comment: is there any way around to get the output (2015-11-10T10:24:53+00:00), as it is, since i don't plan on doing any date based queries in future?

Comment: @user1357790 You could just index it as a StrField if you're not going to query it (as a date), but I would probably recommend handling it in your display layer anyway.

Comment: when i try to index it as a StrField, the output is 1447151093000, can u explain me it with an example?

Comment: If you just changed the field type, it will return the already indexed value. You'll have to change the file type and actually index the string value that you want present. If you're using a layer (such as DIH etc.) and are converting timestamps when indexing, you'll have to check that layer for a solution.

Comment: i can half away understand ur solution. what exactly u mean by file type here? i am not using DIH here anyway, if possible explain with an example ?

Comment: How are you indexing your content? If you're indexing "2015-11-10T10:24:53+00:00" into a StrField, it will not be returned as "1447151093000". If you've changed the type of the field from a date field to a strfield and not reindexed (reimported data into Solr), that might be what you get back. So reindex first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Ur valuable advice, worked finally. it's my fault that i didn't catch u early. moreover it is a good idea to convert date formats in a display layer.